# Discrete Math - Combinatorics question about number of paths in an m x n lattice from one corner to another

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Explain why the number of shortest paths in an $m \times n$ lattice from one corner to another is 
$${s \choose r}$$
where 
$$s = \text{total # of steps$\qquad$ and $\qquad r= $ total # of right steps}$$

I realize $r$ could also be total number of $up$ steps and I realize the solution needs to be explained recursively, that is, I realize that it resembles pascal's triangle where the number of shortest paths to one point is the sum of the shortest number of paths to the 2 points before that point, but I'm not sure where to go from there or how to explain it clearly. It's for a paper and I'm not sure how to set it up.

In addition, by shortest path I mean one where the number of moves is (m-1) + (n-1).

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem. First, it's clear that an optimum path (from Left-Down to Right-Up) must have only Left and Up steps. Then, note that all optimum paths have $s=r+s$ steps with $r$ right and $u$ up steps, with $r$ $u$ fixed (given by $m-1$ and $n-1$). Then, you can establish a one-to-one map between each optimum path and a binary sequence with $r$ zeroes and $u$ ones. But there are ${s \choose r}$ such sequences.

Comment: Is there a formal proof for this somewhere? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your question is something like [this](http://projecteuler.net/problem=15) problem.

It's simple really.

You have *n* number of right steps and *m* number of down steps. *n* and *m* equal this *s* total number of steps. No matter what path you take, there are always the same amount of right steps and the same amount of down steps, and the total amount of steps is always the same.

So what differentiates between different paths? Well, the difference is only the arrangements of right and down steps.

For a two by two lattice, as in the link, there are six combinations:

rrdd, rdrd, drdr, rddr, drrd, ddrr

How many ways can you arrange these?

$s!=$ ways to arrange *s*
$n!=$ ways to arrange *n*
$m!=$ ways to arrange *m*
$m=s-n$

total combos:
$\frac{s!}{n!(s-n)!}=\binom{s}{n}=\binom{s}{s-n}=\binom{s}{m}$

Comment: Hi there, we were told that we weren't allowed to use that formula because we hadn't proved it in class yet. So even if I can explain why there are $s!$ ways to arrange $s$ etc..., I wouldn't be able to conclude that \frac{s!}{n!(s-n)!}. Is there a formal proof of this problem anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: tip: put the latex in $$
I haven't found a formal proof, but I'll try to make it clearer: You can arrange *1234* in 24 ways, or 4!. However, if you want to arrange *rrdd* then you have only six combinations. The reason is that one *r* is the same as another *r*, and same with the *d*'s. So divide the total arrangements by the ways to arrange the *r*'s and the ways to arrange the *d*'s, which turns out to be the definition of combination. I'm not sure what you mean by "that formula", but I believe this is a correct way to think about this problem. Good luck

Comment: Go here: http://projecteuler.net/problem=15, solve the problem, and read the giant discussion on the question. I'm sure you will find what you are looking for.