# Mary needs to go to work

Tags: combinatorics

This was on my combinatorics exam. I definitely didn't answer it correctly, but I'll explain what I did.

Mary has to go to work or some bs. She needs to travel 6 blocks east and 7 blocks north. How many different routes can she take? Honestly, Mary, pick one route and stick to it. You don't need to know all the different ways you can walk to the same place.

Then they throw a wrench in the gears and tell you she has to go 2 blocks east and 4 blocks north first before she takes her daughter to preschool, and then go to work. How many ways can she do this?

First I tried 13! which seemed too large. Then I started thinking like a decision tree. I tried to imagine the scale of the tree in considering my answer. I was somehow led to thinking in terms of binary decisions. So I ended up writing $2^{13}$ because I figured she had 2 decisions to make at each block, but clearly, that's just not true. By my incorrect logic, she could go north 13 times.

Comment: She has to go 13 blocks. 6 have to be East, 7 have to be North. How many ways are there to choose which 7 of the 13 will be North?

Comment: This is almost the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534735/possible-ways-to-walk-to-school

Comment: "has to go to work or some bs" yup that about sums it up :P

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  For the first problem, you have $13$ blocks, of which any $6$ can be east.  For the second problem, you start with going $6$ blocks, of which any $2$ can be east.  After dropping her daughter, how many blocks east and north remain?

Answer (score 0):

She first needs to travel $2$ blocks east and $4$ blocks north. She needs to go $6$ blocks total to get to the preschool and of these $6$, she needs to go east twice and north four times, so ${6\choose 2}$ number of ways to get to the day care, (go east twice). Can you do the rest?